# How to display a jpg in tkinter python 3.3 without PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, jpeg

I have not installed PIL and I'm not planning on it. But I want to display a jpg on my tkinter window.

I know that it is possible to display gifs and bitmaps with PhotoImage but I need to be able to view a jpg or have an easy way to convert jpg to gif or bitmap.

Comment: Also , if possible, i'd like to not install any other libraries

Comment: I'm 95% sure this is impossible with just built-in modules.

Comment: @Kevin, if it's possible to display a bitmap then its possible to display any kind of image without using any other libraries than those used for the displaying

Comment: Please excuse my imprecise language. It's possible, but not feasible, to write your own jpeg-to-bmp converter. I say this because Wikipedia's [syntax and encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpg#Syntax_and_structure) sections are like ten pages long and crammed with matrices and Greek letters, so it looks way harder than just downloading PIL.

Comment: It seems weird the tkinter would require another package in order to display an image in a GUI.  I'm developing a GUI SDK that's purely tkinter based and don't want to require my users to have to install PIL.